# WordPress - How to block Access to specific files or directories for users that are not logged in?

Tags: php, wordpress, block

On my WordPress web site hundreds of login attempts by bots are observed.
They try to log in with user name that do exist in the system.

I want to stop this!

I found out, that these bots get the information about existing users from the URL
mydomain.de/wp-json/wp/v2/users/

So I tried to block access to these files with the following code I found in other articles:

```
    add_filter( 'rest_authentication_errors', function( $result ) {
        // If a previous authentication check was applied,
        // pass that result along without modification.
        if ( true === $result || is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
            return $result;
        }

        // No authentication has been performed yet.
        // Return an error if user is not logged in.
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
            return new WP_Error(
                'rest_not_logged_in',
                __( 'You are not currently logged in.' ),
                array( 'status' => 401 )
            );
        }
     
        // Our custom authentication check should have no effect
        // on logged-in requests
        return $result;
    });
```

With this, all those login attacks stopped.

But unfortunately this also stoped my addon CONTACT FORM 7 from working!
I use this as a contact form for users that are not logged in.
The addon tries to access
/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/9589/feedback
and this is blocked by the code.

How cat I avoid this?
Users that are not logged in should be able to use the web site.
The should only be blocked from getting these "internal informations" from /wp-json/wp/v2/users/ and alike.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try this plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-wp-rest-api/#description ?

Comment: Thanks for the hint.
I just tested it. Unfortunately it does the same thing as my code above.
The complete REST-API is disabled. 
As a consequence CONTACT FORM 7 is not running anymore...

Disabling the whole REST API is too restrictive.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with addon

WP Cerber Security

which is able to block all rest api calls except for certain name-spaces like contact-form-7.